Reconstruct microwave image from S21 data
Can you take a look at my code? I have tried so hard to reconstruct my 2D image from S21 data, but it failed every time.
function [BPI] = backproject3(ReS21, ImS21, THETA)
% Function to perform backprojection using a Ram-Lak filter

    % Calculate the magnitude from ReS21 and ImS21
    PR = sqrt(ReS21.^2 + ImS21.^2);
    
    % Apply Ram-Lak filter to projections (you can keep or skip filtering)
    filtPR = PR;  % Or use: filtPR = ramLakFilter(PR); if you have a filter function

    % Convert angles (THETA) to radians
    th = (pi/180) * THETA;
    
    % Initialize the image (backprojected image) with zeros
    n = size(PR, 1);
    sideSize = n;
    m = length(THETA); 
    BPI = zeros(sideSize, sideSize);
    
    % Find the middle index of the projections
    midindex = (n + 1) / 2;
    
    % Set up x and y matrices
    x = 1:sideSize;
    y = 1:sideSize;
    [X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
    xpr = X - (sideSize + 1) / 2;
    ypr = Y - (sideSize + 1) / 2;
    
    % Loop over each projection
    for i = 1:m
        disp(['On angle ', num2str(THETA(i))]);

        % Calculate filtered index for projection at current angle
        filtIndex = round(midindex + xpr * sin(th(i)) - ypr * cos(th(i)));

        % Ensure indices are within bounds
        BPIa = zeros(sideSize, sideSize);
        spota = find((filtIndex > 0) & (filtIndex <= n));
        newfiltIndex = filtIndex(spota);
        
        % Add the filtered projections to the corresponding image locations
        BPIa(spota) = filtPR(newfiltIndex(:), i);
        BPI = BPI + BPIa;
    end
    
    % Normalize the backprojected image by dividing by the number of angles
    BPI = BPI ./ m;
end

% Sample usage
ReS21 = [-1.31E-02, -1.31E-02, -1.33E-02, -1.27E-02, -1.23E-02, -1.19E-02, -1.20E-02, -1.14E-02, -1.07E-02, -1.03E-02, ...
    -1.02E-02, -9.38E-03, -8.81E-03, -8.62E-03, -7.87E-03, -7.56E-03, -7.27E-03, -6.97E-03, -7.03E-03, -6.72E-03, ...
    -6.81E-03, -6.80E-03, -7.20E-03, -7.90E-03, -7.83E-03, -8.65E-03, -9.49E-03, -1.0232272E-02, -1.07E-02, -1.18E-02, ...
    -1.24E-02, -1.34E-02, -1.27E-02, -1.31E-02, -1.30E-02];
ImS21 = [9.33E-02, 9.33E-02, 0.092850951, 9.23E-02, 9.20E-02, 9.18E-02, 9.17E-02, 9.10E-02, 9.10E-02, 9.15E-02, ...
    9.20E-02, 0.093250948, 9.44E-02, 9.58E-02, 9.71E-02, 9.75E-02, 9.83E-02, 9.88E-02, 9.85E-02, 9.89E-02, ...
    9.83E-02, 9.79E-02, 0.097380504, 9.72E-02, 9.70E-02, 9.67E-02, 9.65E-02, 9.71E-02, 9.75E-02, 0.098243275, ...
    9.82E-02, 9.78E-02, 9.75E-02, 9.69E-02, 9.64E-02];
angles = 10:10:350;

% Call the function
BPI = backproject3(ReS21, ImS21, angles);

% Display the final image (backprojected)
imagesc(BPI);
colormap('gray');
colorbar;
title('Backprojected Image');


Look at Matlab’s iradon() function

Are you still interested in this or have you figured it out?

Yes, I kinda got the codes to the point I could see my reconstructed image. But there are so much noises and random line. Could you please take a look at it?

Saw your message. I see the data, but I don't see any code for how to extract the data. I think what you are ultimately missing is the difference between the projection grid and the imaging grid. The projection sample points may not directly lie on the image grid, so you have to figure out how to estimate the value of the projections at the image grid points.

Here is my new codes:

I don't see a new link
